# How to get ASIN code on Amazon using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c

I cannot get ASIN from Amazon using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.

"document.title" is working but "document.getElementById" is not working.

I checked my javascript code on Chrome javascript console & it's working, but it doesn’t work on iPhone simulator & real iPhone.

Is there any mistake?


**[Amazon Website]**
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1927925576/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1927925576)


**[.m file]**

```
-(void)getAmazonASIN:(id)sender {

    // get Title: Working
    NSString* amazonItemTitle = [self.AFFWEB stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.title;"];
    NSLog(@"document.title: %@", amazonItemTitle);

    // get ASIN: Not Working
    NSString* amazonJavascript = @"document.getElementById('ASIN').value";
    NSString* amazonItemASIN = [self.AFFWEB stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:amazonJavascript];
    NSLog(@"ASIN: %@", amazonItemASIN);

    NSString* amazonJavascript2 = @"document.getElementById(\"ASIN\").value";                                                               
    NSString* amazonItemASIN2 = [self.AFFWEB stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:amazonJavascript2];
    NSLog(@"ASIN2: %@", amazonItemASIN2);
}
```

**[Log]**

```
2015-09-15 00:50:03.857 AmazonASIN [32315:6669048] document.title: Persona 4 Volume 1 (Persona 4 Gn)
2015-09-15 00:50:03.859 AmazonASIN [32315:6669048] ASIN: 
2015-09-15 00:50:03.860 AmazonASIN [32315:6669048] ASIN2:
```

**[Chrome javascript console]**

```
>document.getElementById('ASIN').value
>"1927925576"
```

Answer (score 0):

After iPhone loads Amazon website, it jumps to Amazon mobile website like this:
[http://www.amazon.com/dp/1927925576/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1927925576) -> [http://www.amazon.com/dp/1927925576/ref=cm_sw_su_dp](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1927925576)

On this page, the source shows that ASIN is “asin”, not capital..

```
document.getElementById(“asin").value
```

Thx!